# Collapsing pandas groupby object without aggregation function

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have data like this:

```
+--------+-------+----------+  
| module | topic | duration |  
+--------+-------+----------+  
| a      | a     |        1 |  
| a      | b     |        3 |  
| a      | a     |        5 |  
| b      | d     |        6 |  
| b      | e     |        6 |  
| b      | f     |        3 |  
+--------+-------+----------+
```

which I want to convert to data like this:

```
+--------+-------+
| module | topic |
+--------+-------+
| a      | a     |
| a      | b     |
| b      | d     |
| b      | e     |
| b      | f     |
+--------+-------+
```

In Python with pandas I could do the following

```python
topics.groupby(['module', 'topic'], as_index=False).size().reset_index(name='count').drop(['count'], axis=1)
```

but there has to be a better way than that! How do I group a data-frame in pandas without running each group through an aggregation function?

Comment: try `drop_duplicates` `df.drop_duplicates(['module', 'topic'])`

Comment: If you group, you have to do something with the groups. If you aren't trying to do anything, you just want to remove duplicates it seems.

Comment: if you add`.drop('duration', axis=1)` to @WeNYoBen 's answer you get your expected output.

Comment: Thanks all, I went with `df[['module', 'topic']].drop_duplicates()`. I've been so stuck into `group_by` I forgot to think outside that!